# Add 2 network interface for few VM based on the naming convention BICEP

Tags: azure-bicep

Add 2 network interface for few VM based on the naming convention BICEP
for ex

if the VM name has xyz in the name it should apply 2 nic and for rest it should apply 1 NIC

Comment: Pasting the code here
var nics = [
  {
    ids: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', '${VMName}-nic') 
    properties:{
      primary: true
    }
  }
  {
    ids: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', '${VMName}-nic2') 
    properties:{
      primary: false
    }
  }
]
networkProfile : [for nic in nics: {
      networkInterfaces: {
        id : [
          nic.ids
        ]

      }
    }]

Comment: Could you please edit your question ? it will easier for people to understand.

Comment: are the NIC created as part of the template as well ?